# LXD local pylxd.Client connection sees no containers while "lxc list" command lists a dozen

Tags: python, lxd

On a ubuntu 16.04 machine with lxd 2.21, the following code returns all my containers:

```
from pylxd import Client
client = Client()
client.containers.all()
```

On a ubuntu 18.04 machine with lxd 3.0.1, the same code returns an empty list

On both machines, the command `lxc list` returns many containers,
for some reason the client connection on the newer lxd host is not "seeing" the containers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set this environment variable:

```
export LXD_DIR=/var/lib/lxd
```

The api uses the socket `/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket` by default, and in my installation the proper socket to use is `/var/lib/lxd/unix.socket`

```
from pylxd import Client
os.environ["LXD_DIR"] = "/var/lib/lxd"
client = Client()
client.containers.all()
```